# No line breaks using flexbox at IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

When you run this snippet with different browsers, you can see IE does not apply line breaks.

What did I forget or how to fix this?

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>
  Title
  </h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </p>
  <a>Button</a>
</div>
```

Comment: working fine on IE11

Comment: I haven't windows 10 overhere, so let's say IE edge and lower ;)

Comment: Actually I can't really run down which css property is doing this. I can not mimic the same issue for Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the solution..

This simple line of css is helping me out.

```css
p {
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add "width: 100%;" to paragraf

```
div p { width: 100%; }
```

an You don't need "display:block" in div, because "display: flex;" overwrite this.

And IE 9, 8 not suporrt "display:flex;"